# R type coercion error with R version 4.0.5

Tags: r

I'm just starting to use R again after a couple of years being out of the scene.

I'm using this older package "tradesys" (not maintained anymore) which has it's own datatype called expr.frame.
This used to work great but with the newest version of R (4.0.5) i am now getting an error if i try to coerce an expr.frame to a data.frame:

```
> library(tradesys)
> ef <- expr.frame(1, list(St=quote(signalmap(el=c(T)))))
> ef
$x
[1] "x"

$St
[1] 1

attr(,"class")
[1] "expr.frame"
attr(,"row.names")
[1] "1"
attr(,"exprlist")
attr(,"exprlist")$St
signalmap(el = c(T))

> class(ef)
[1] "expr.frame"

> as.data.frame(ef)
Error in as.data.frame.default(ef) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"expr.frame"’ to a data.frame
```

This coerce error is funny because expr.frame has it's own coercion function for this:

```
> as.data.frame.expr.frame
function (x, ...) 
{
    structure(x, exprlist = NULL, class = "data.frame")
}
<bytecode: 0x558670386748>
<environment: namespace:tradesys>
```

This function is obviously not found/resolved as indicated by the error message, because as.data.frame.default() is called instead.

If I call the coercion function explicitly it works like a charm:

```
> as.data.frame.expr.frame(ef)
  x St
1 x  1
```

Here is my sessinInfo():

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.5 (2021-03-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS:   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/blas/libblas.so.3.9.0
LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lapack/liblapack.so.3.9.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=nl_NL.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=nl_NL.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=nl_NL.UTF-8     LC_MONETARY=nl_NL.UTF-8   
 [6] LC_MESSAGES=nl_NL.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=nl_NL.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                  LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=nl_NL.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] quantmod_0.4.18 TTR_0.24.2      xts_0.12.1      tradesys_0.1    RUnit_0.4.32    zoo_1.8-9      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.0.5  tools_4.0.5     curl_4.3        grid_4.0.5      lattice_0.20-41
```

Why is the coerce function not found anymore if i call as.data.frame(ef)?

Comment: Just a guess, but if `tradesys` is [this](https://github.com/r-forge/tradesys/tree/master/pkg) package then it seems like there is no `NAMESPACE` file for the package, so possibly it's old enough to have been written before namespaces were a requirement! No idea how R handles these older packages, but it could be that the lack of a namespace means S3 methods (such as `as.data.frame.expr.frame()`) aren't exported. If you're desperate to use this package you could possible clone it and create a `NAMESPACE` yourself, but probably you just shouldn't be using the package any more.

Comment: I install the tradesys package locally where it has the following NAMESPACE:           `# Default NAMESPACE created by R
# Remove the previous line if you edit this file

# Export all names
exportPattern(".")

# Import all packages listed as Imports or Depends
import(
  zoo,
  RUnit
)` This should export everything in the package right?

Comment: Yeah, I think methods should be exported in that case. Try looking at the dispatch using `sloop`. This might give an idea of what's going on behind the scenes: `sloop::s3_dispatch(as.data.frame(ef))`

Comment: If I try that i get:`> sloop::s3_dispatch(as.data.frame(ef))
=> as.data.frame.expr.frame
 * as.data.frame.default` What does that mean?

Comment: If I do a traceback() it shows that it goes straight to the as.data.frame.default() function: `> as.data.frame(ef)
Error in as.data.frame.default(ef) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"expr.frame"’ to a data.frame
> traceback()
3: stop(gettextf("cannot coerce class %s to a data.frame", sQuote(deparse(class(x))[1L])), 
       domain = NA)
2: as.data.frame.default(ef)
1: as.data.frame(ef)
`

Comment: That's really strange. The `=>` indicates that `as.data.frame.expr.frame()` is the method that will be used, so I'm not sure at all why you're getting that error. Very sorry but I think without access to the `tradesys` package I'm at a loss as to what the issue could be!